# Reverse P/Invoke tutorial?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, pinvoke

I've a old C/C++ class that i want to refactor and access from .net using PInvoke

All P/Invoke tutorials refers to call win32 api but i haven't found anything to code the other side

Any tips/ideas ? my c/c++ experience is pretty rusty :(

UPDATE - this is for wrapping existing C/C++ code so it can called from .net using P/Invoke

How do i define the C function so from .net i can get the value using ref/out strings

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to call a C/C++ DLL (other than the win32 api) from C# or trying to call C# code from C/C++?

Comment: What is a C/C++ class?  You cannot directly use C++ classes with P/Invoke, a wrapper is required.

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite the existing c/c++ code so it can be called from .net

Comment: What you are trying to do is not reverse P/Invoke. You just want to know how to write the native side of the P/Invoke. The key is for it to be a C-style function, not member function of a C++ class.

Comment: That's correct - it was simpler to write ( & hopefully convey) Reverse to denote the other side of the equation

Comment: Generally "reverse P/Invoke" means native code calling managed code without going through COM. Callbacks and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you find help 
[C++ Interop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984)
[Walkthrough: Porting an Existing Native C++ Application to Interoperate with .NET Framework Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979)
[Use Our ManWrap Library to Get the Best of .NET in Native C++ Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/april/use-our-manwrap-library-to-use-net-in-native-c-code)
[How to call C++ code from Managed, and vice versa (Interop)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160120205633/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/deeptanshuv/archive/2005/06/26/432870.aspx)

Comment: The 2nd link is good but stopped short of sample for how to get a reference to the string back to .net/managed code !!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way in my experience is to make your C++ class into a COM class (or create a helper class for this purpose) and then add a reference to it in your .NET project.

If you want to access the .NET object from C++ then the opposite is true, mark it as `ComVisible` and use [tlbexp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfzzah2c.aspx) to create a TLB for the native code to import (then you can use it as a regular COM object).

Comment: making it com compatible would be way over my head 
This is essentially to read some custom binary data so pinvoke seems simplest if i can figure out how to return ref/out strings

Comment: @Kumar, you don't have to make the whole class COM compatible, just create a little COM object with one function that calls this native function. Otherwise you can use P/Invoke, have you tried `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out string s`?

Comment: I am a VC++ newbie, any pointers/samples on how to get that, nothing shows on google search for com compatible class etc.

Comment: COM is the slowest form of interop and generally the most work on the native side. Not my first choice.