# Exporting a native C function from a .net DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, interop, native-code

I have a .net assembly written in C#, and I'm looking to export a native C function from the assembly.

I have an application which will perform a 'LoadLibrary()' on any DLL's found in a 'plugin' folder.  After loading the DLL, the application performs a 'GetProcAddress' looking for a function named 'Register'.  The application expects this function to follow the C calling convention.

How can I export a function named 'Register' from my .net assembly, so I can successfully hookup with the plugin system for this application?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at [Unmanaged Exports](http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports).

Comment: What is this tool. The link is blocked for me on my network.

Comment: @CathalMF: https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports

Answer (score 3):

Write a .Net library in Managed C++ and there you can export a "Native" method/function.

Comment: it's doable but mixed mode C++ SUCKS!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Microsoft does not support this feature, and you have to change the msil after the build to expose those methods.
It is possible as one guy has shown a reasonable solution
on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DllExporter.aspx) or [here](http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/),
but it requires a post build step and you are on your own after that.
I don't know if this hack will work on .net 4.0 or later though.
Hopefully Microsoft will listen to us and support this simple feature in C# since the CLR support is already there.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [Reverse P/Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008874/reverse-p-invoke-tutorial). You can't actually embed a C function in a C# dll, if by that you mean a function actually implemented in C, but by following the tutorials given on the linked page you can create a DLL export that's callable by unmanaged C/C++ code.

Comment: None of those answers address his needs; he isn't using COM.