# how do I use C# dll in powerbuilder?

Tags: c#, dll, powerbuilder

So I created a dll in Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express and I want to use the dll in PowerBuilder 11.5. 
To test, I created a simple sum function in the c# dll, declared it in PowerBuilder using the syntax `Function int sum(int x, int y)` **Library "NETS.dll"** in the Global External Functions in PowerBuilder, and called the function when the powerbuilder window opens or when I press a command button but everytime I try running, PowerBuilder says "**unknown function name**".
 Need help.
 Thanks

Comment: Isn't that importable via http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc00357_1100/html/newfeat/CEGIBCHA.htm

Comment: Content not found in the above link!

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to expose your DLL as a COM object, register it on the system with `regasm.exe` and use it via and `OLEObject` and `ConnectToNewObject` PowerScript function.

Answer (score 2):

A C# assembly won't have any exported functions that you can import this way. You can read up on this questiion:
[Exporting a native C function from a .net DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993719/exporting-a-native-c-function-from-a-net-dll)
Hope that it will help you!