# How to export c# dll functions to be able to access them from another application

Tags: c#

I would like to know how can I export dll functions because I have a program which requires function exporting in order to use them.

Can I accomplish this in c#?

PS: The program who's using the dll is not O.Source and I can't add the reference into it.

Comment: Do you mean you need to access the methods of dll in other application ?

Comment: Is the other application a .NET application?

Comment: Yes to access the dll methods in other application . The other application is coded in python or delphi :-? not sure

Comment: For the Delphi or Python you may want to look at Exporting and or Interop

Answer (score 0):

1 You can use `MEF Framework` - Based on `Export, Import` and `Catalog`

Link :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx.

2 You can also expose on your network by using  `WCF`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119(v=vs.90).aspx

Nota : You have another possibilities, it depends on your choice and technical constraints

Answer (score 0):

If the other application is a .NET application, it can add a *reference* to your assembly (DLL), and use any `public` type defined within the assembly.  This gives it full access to your code.

If you need a native API for use with your C# code, then this becomes more difficult.  There are  a few options:

1. Use COM.  You can [mark types as ComVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182157%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and register the assembly.  This allows your code to be accessed via COM.
2. Use C++/CLI to build a native wrapper around your managed types.  This would require a separate assembly (DLL) that provides the native exports, and uses the managed types internally.

The best option here really depends on how the "other application" needs to gain access to your code.  If it's not a .NET application, COM is typically the simplest (and often nicest) option.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the closest option to your requirement would be using [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports).

For other options, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4818940/908336) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6613770/908336).